# In summer the sliding door to the garden is open and insects come in through it

Tags: domestic-animals

I enjoy having the sliding door open in warm weather. After the sliding door are some stone slabs and then lawn and plants.

Are there any tricks that really help to have less or no insects?

I would like to avoid chemicals if possible.

Comment: You must be in one of those "no-screen" places. Become the person who introduces the concept of a screen for your sliding door to your area. Coming from an an area where that's standard, *not* having one seems simply *insane.*

Comment: Another concern here would be mice (they like to come in open doors, sometimes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends where you live - some countries have mesh screens that act as doors inside the main door, so you could look at getting one of those fitted. In the UK, we manage with voile or nets over the open door, or those plastic strip curtain type things or bead curtains hung in the doorway. I have my balcony door and windows open all the time in summer with nothing over them though - I only get flies coming in and staying in if there's food about anywhere, and I never have a light on indoors after dark if the doors and windows are open to stop mosquitoes and moths coming in.

Comment: Sorry, Bamboo, but mosquitoes are attracted to carbon dioxide, not light. They're much worse at night than in the daytime where I live. As for screening, yeah, that's extremely common in the US - I've never seen a patio door here without a screen door, although I do think there are some places where they don't use screens.

Comment: I know its carbon dioxide,but in the UK, you get more in if you have the lights on... but then our mosquitoes are really just gnats/midges, though they still give a nasty itchy bite.  I hardly ever get any in here any more, not since my younger son moved out - he attracts mosquitoes from  miles around for some reason...

Comment: My wife also attracts mosquitoes, which protects me quite well. :)  As for a screenless patio door and darkness, I'd be far more afraid of getting a bat in the house than anything else. Of course, if it got in, it would eat the mosquitoes, so there's that...